# How to generate .d.ts and .Designer.cs files from .resx file

Tags: typescript, msbuild, csproj

I am working with a slightly older Typescript project which is large enough that it takes a while to build everything. But sometimes when I'm adding a bunch of strings to the resx file, I just want to generate the d.ts file without having to build the whole project so I can more quickly add those resources in ts files with intellisense in VS Code.

First off, I don't know exactly what the process in msbuild is to generate those two strongly typed files. I assume it is keying off of the `<RunLocalization>true</RunLocalization>` property in the csproj file but I can't find any documentation on that property. Moreover, I don't see how I can specify to run localization without compiling the project and running through all of the Targets.

Secondly, I can use ResGen.exe to create the Designer.cs file though it is in a slightly different format than what msbuild produces. I don't think I actually need this file for my local development as I think it is only used by the framework which consumes our project. So maybe I can get by with only generating the d.ts file and build the designer file when I run the slower full build. But ResGen.exe does not support TS as a language.

Any way to generate at least a resource.d.ts file from a resources.resx file? I would prefer a built-in way (e.g. with msbuild) but I don't mind a 3rd party tool.